# Comparing positive vs negative numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a Javascript function that counts the number of sorted numbers in a given array. For some reason it works for all positive numbers, but when the array contains negative numbers, the function behaves as if the negative numbers are positive. Any ideas on why this occurs

```
countUniqueValues = (a) => {
    if(a.length === 0){return 0;}
    
    let i = 0;
    let j = 1;

    while(a[j]){
        if(a[i] === a[j]){
            j++;
        } 
        else if(a[i] !== a[j]){
            i++;
            a[i] = a[j];
        }
    }
    return i+1;
}
```

```
console.log(countUniqueValues([-2,-1,-1,0,1])); // return 2 and should return 4
```

Comment: `a[i++];` HUH?....

Comment: Well `while(a[j])` is going to stop when it hits that `0`.  That seems like an immediate bug.

Comment: If you want to figure out why it returns 2, break out a pencil and paper and start stepping through it.  Or you can use your browser debugger.

Comment: Just so you know, it's not working with some positive sets either, I tested [2,4,5,6,5] for example.

Comment: `i` gets adjusted to `1` and sets `a[1]` equal to itself.  Then the values are all equal until the `a[j]` terminates early due to the `0`.  And then `1 + 1` results in `2`

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to mention this is for a sorted array

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which will deduplicate primitive values:

```js
const countUniqueValues = arr => new Set(arr).size;

console.log(countUniqueValues([-2,-1,-1,0,1]));
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the "_Any ideas on why this occurs_".

Comment: @Ivar Yes, to be honest, I did not really understand what the idea behind the code in the question was supposed to be... it does not really make sense

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = [-2,-1,-1,0,1];
var unique = a.filter(onlyUnique);

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
 return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

console.log(unique.length);
```

This will work!
Yours doesnt work because you never increment I or J